# Chart js Tooltips for my graph is displaying all data as a group while hovering on a single bar

Tags: laravel, chart.js

Why is this happen, please look at the snap below!

[snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0Ehd.png)

my data from the server for is an arrays of 12 size as months shown on the labels

`   var sales = {{ $sales }};
var profit = {{ $profit }};
var loss = {{ $loss }};

```
    //business trend monthly
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        // Line chart
        new Chart(document.getElementById("mychartjs"), {
            type: "bar",
            data: {
                labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
                datasets: [{
                label: "Sales",
                fill: true,
                backgroundColor: 'blue',
                borderWidth:0,
                data: sales
                },
                {
                label: "profit",
                fill: true,
                backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 78, 0)",
                borderWidth:0,
                data: profit
                },
                {
                label: "loss",
                fill: true,
                backgroundColor: "#dc3545",
                borderWidth:0,
                data: loss
                }]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                plugins: {
                    legend: {
                        display: false,
                        boxWidth: 0
                    },
                    title: {
                        display: false,
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot tell why this happens in your case because when I run your code, the tooltip always only displays the value of a single bar. You can however explicitly define `options.plugins.tooltip.mode: 'nearest'` (or any other suitable `mode`) in order to obtain the desired behavior.

For further information, consult [Tooltip Configuratio](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-configuration)n from the Chart.js documentation.

Please take a look at your amended and runnable code below.

```js
const sales = [120, 130, 125, 132, 115, 96, 87, 92, 105, 111, 105, 142];
const profit = [12, 13, 5, 18, 6, 3, 0, 0, 0, 8, 13, 25];
const loss = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 12, 8, 0, 0, 0];

new Chart("mychartjs", {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
    datasets: [{
        label: "Sales",
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
        borderWidth: 0,
        data: sales
      },
      {
        label: "profit",
        backgroundColor: "green",
        borderWidth: 0,
        data: profit
      },
      {
        label: "loss",
        backgroundColor: "red",
        borderWidth: 0,
        data: loss
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false,
        boxWidth: 0
      },
      title: {
        display: false,
      },
      tooltip: {
        mode: 'nearest'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@^4"></script>
<canvas id="mychartjs"></canvas>
```